# Play Framework Assets.at to java.io.File

Tags: java, playframework

In the Play Framework we have a helper method `controllers.Assets.at(String, String, boolean)` [as described here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Assets#The-Assets-controller).

Also in the Play Framework it is [described here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaStream#Serving-files) that the `ok()` method contains helpers that automatically compute the necessary response headers when serving a `java.io.File` inside of it like this:

```
public Result index() {
    return ok(new java.io.File("/tmp/fileToServe.pdf"));
}
```

My question is how to combine the two. Currently I have something like this:

```
public static Result index() {
    return ok(new File(controllers.Assets.at("public/", "music/test.mp3", false).toString()));
}
```

This obviously does not work because the `toString()` method on `controllers.Assets.at()` descibes the object in a string, not the objects' content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Assets` works with Result, but you can take a look at the `Application` class instead

```
// Get the current app
final Application app = Play.application();
final File file = app.getFile("public/music/test.mp3");
```

More info [here](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/java/play/Application.java#L53-L61), but the implementation is

```
/**
 * Get a file relative to the application root path.
 *
 * @param relativePath relative path of the file to fetch
 * @return a file instance - it is not guaranteed that the file exists
 */
default File getFile(String relativePath) {
    return getWrappedApplication().getFile(relativePath);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Weird that this isn't a part of Assets.

Comment: This does not seem to work in a production environment. My guess, it is so because the assets are packed into a jar, but the `getFile` method looks in the path relative to the root of the process.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to combine these two. If you configured your `Play framework` properly, you should have following `route` in `routes` file:

`GET /assets/*file controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)`

Your client can use it to get `test.mp3` with following request:

`GET /assets/music/test.mp3`

Comment: how do you handle this if you use the dist command to package your play framework application

Answer (score 0):

This works for both environments, dev and prod:

```
Play.resourceAsStream("public/...", Play.current()).get()
```